# Restricting std::sort to random access iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator, type-traits

I was just wondering, since you can only pass random access iterators to `std::sort` anyway, why not enforce that restriction by defining it only for random access iterators in the first place?

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ForwardIterator>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
        typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::iterator_category,
        std::random_access_iterator_tag>::value,
    void>
::type sort(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end)
{
    // ...
}
```

I find a single line error message a lot easier to read than pages and pages of error messages resulting from type errors far down in the implementation.

You could do the same with other algorithms. The standard C++ core language has always been expressive enough for that task, right? So, any particular reason why this was not done?

Comment: I suspect: no `enable_if` in C++03, and generally most applications of TMP were rudimentary at the time of the deadline for inclusion of significant features in the standard, which would have been 1997-ish.

Comment: @Steve: That's why I said *core language*. It only takes five lines to implement `enable_if`.

Comment: @FredOverflow: quite, so the fact that it isn't there strongly suggests to me that this area wasn't well-developed. Another possibility is to support use of `sort` with iterators which actually are random-access, but which under-estimate their category. Nowadays you expect people to be able to get iterator categories right, maybe not so much in 1997, so perhaps at the time is was useful that the standard doesn't *require* that incorrectly-tagged iterators are rejected by `sort`.

Comment: A pointer is a random access iterator. Does a pointer pass the test you propose?

Comment: @Oswald: yes it does. `iterator_traits` is partially specialized for pointers.

Comment: @Oswald: Yes, `std::iterator_traits` defines all pointers as random access iterators.

Comment: @FredOverflow: possibly see also, "how come it's 2011, and still beyond the wit of humankind to get concepts into the C++ standard?"

Comment: @Steve: Good point about underestimating the category, I hadn't thought of that...

Comment: Surely this is just a QoI issue? The standard specifies an interface, not an implementation; it just requires the implementation provide a `sort` that works with random access iterators. It shouldn't matter to conforming code whether the implementation provides a specialization for bidi iterators as an extension, whether it provides an "improved" compile error if you try to use a bidi iterator with `sort` or whether it just lets the "natural" error message fall through.

Comment: @Charles: This question isn’t about conformance, it’s about ease of use.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yes. What makes you think I thought otherwise? @FredOverflow hasn't specified a particular implementation, though, when he asked "why this was not done?".

Comment: @Charles: I wasn’t sure … you made a reference to the standard arguing that it doesn’t proscribe such a check, that’s all.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: My point was it doesn't _prohibit_ such a check. As I understand it - and I may be wrong - the signature in @FredOverflow's example reduces to that mandated by the standard for random access iterator types so there is no reason an implementation couldn't choose to do so. This was the basis for my assertion that it was a quality of implementation issue.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure your proposed `std::sort` would be conforming... is there actually a requirement that `iterator_traits` must be specialized for a type in order for it to be used as an iterator?  (I did a cursory search of the Iterators and Algorithms library specs but didn't see anything that would require this.)

Comment: @James: yes, 24.3.1/1 says, "it is required that if `Iterator` is the type of an iterator, the types (blah blah) be defined". I think this should be taken as part of the definition of the word "iterator" as used anywhere else in the standard, so when `std::sort` (actually, the algorithms section in general, 25/4) says that its parameters are iterators, that means it's undefined to call it with something that isn't one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The core language has always been expressive enough to handle such checks, but when the first standard was being prepared (around 1996/1997), the tricks that you can play with SFINAE (what [enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) is based upon) were not yet known and the support for advanced template wizardry was limited in the compilers.

So, the reason why the standard did not mandate it was because the needed techniques were not invented yet.
The reason why compiler/library writers did not add it after the fact is probably just plain economics: not enough people asked for the feature, and when people did start asking for better diagnostics, hope was on the [concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29) proposal to take care of it. Unfortunately, this proved to be a bit too hard to get finalised in time.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that SFINAE was invented (or discovered) after the standard library implementations had reached a certain maturity. After that, changes to the core library had to be very justified in order to prevent the introduction of regressions and I guess that mere cosmetics are somewhat hard to justify.

That said, the GCC for example already *does* have a lot of diagnostics for template-related error messages, e.g. macros that perform a kind of concept checking. For example, the GCC-libstdc++ has the following:

```
// concept requirements
__glibcxx_function_requires(_Mutable_RandomAccessIteratorConcept<
   _RandomAccessIterator>)
__glibcxx_function_requires(_LessThanComparableConcept<_ValueType>)
__glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);
```

Comment: One needs some sort of `#define` to turn those checks on? - However, last time I tried to use those, the error messages didn't appear to improve much, if not the contrary...

Comment: @Uncle: I see. Interesting. Do you know why it’s off by default? The reason isn’t documented in the `bits/concept_check.h` file. One comment suggests that the author of the concept checking wasn’t sure whether the compiler was smart enough to elide the runtime overhead of the checks. Looking at the code it is clear that the compiler *will* do this, however. Then again, the code is from 2000. Perhaps the compiler’s dead code elimination was really that stupid back then.

Comment: there is a mix of static and runtime checks here, the "valid_range" test is done at runtime for example, so it may explain why it's disabled by default.

Comment: @Matthieu: you are right, of course. I completely failed to notice that check – arguably it’s very bad of GCC to throw these different checks in together.

Comment: I agree, it would make sense to distinguish the two categories.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when there is only one overload of an algorithm, you'll nearly always get better diagnostics by causing a compilation error just inside using something like Boost.ConceptCheck or `__glibcxx_function_requires`.  When SFINAE (which is what `enable_if` uses) leaves you with an empty overload set, most compilers simply tell you "there's no matching function," which tends not to be very helpful.

Answer (score -3):

One of the nice things about templates in C++ is they can have a sort of static 'duck typing'. I can't speak for this particular case, but in many templates, as long as you keep the interface the same, all the hierarchy nonsense doesn't matter. And that's a good thing.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question